# How to save kaminari current page as a variable, for link use to go back to page left

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm using the kaminari pagination ruby on rails gem. Each entry I'm pulling has a edit link, which takes user to another page where they can edit. Currently, with :back set for the href value in my link back it always goes to page one.

I'm trying to save the url variable for the page when it clicks, and then set the back link to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to access the browser history and do

```
onclick="window.history.back();"
```

or you could add the variable to your href on the paginated view like.

```
<%= link_to "mymodel", model_path(:prevpage => params[:page]) %>
```

Comment: Hey Jon, I've tried using JS before to access the history and it couldn't load the ajax called paginations. I like your idea of putting hte variable to the href on the paginated view. I'll give it a shot

Comment: model_path should be named whatever your model is ie survey_path or article_path

Answer (score 0):

I add it to cookies, like `cookies[:current_page]`.

And in a show view(or some other action page), add a params to link that redirect to index action page like `articles_path(grid:{page:cookies[:current_page]})`

It's not the best way, but it does the trick.